# How can I unit test a complex promise chain?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js

I have some JavaScript code:

```
var findLeastUsedPassage;

findLeastUsedPassage = function(StudentId) {
  var passageCounts;
  passageCounts = [];
  return db.Passage.findAll({
    where: {
      active: true
    }
  }).each(function(dbPassage) {
    var passage;
    passage = dbPassage.get();
    passage.count = 0;
    return passageCounts.push(passage);
  }).then(function() {
    return db.Workbook.findAll({
      where: {
        SubjectId: 1,
        gradedAt: {
          $ne: null
        },
        StudentId: StudentId
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: db.WorkbookQuestion,
          include: [db.Question]
        }
      ],
      limit: 10,
      order: [['gradedAt', 'DESC']]
    });
  }).each(function(dbWorkbook) {
    return Promise.resolve(dbWorkbook.WorkbookQuestions).each(function(dbWorkbookQuestion) {
      var passageIndex;
      passageIndex = _.findIndex(passageCounts, function(passageCount) {
        return passageCount.id === dbWorkbookQuestion.Question.PassageId;
      });
      if (passageIndex !== -1) {
        return passageCounts[passageIndex].count++;
      }
    });
  }).then(function() {
    passageCounts = _.sortBy(passageCounts, 'count');
    return passageCounts;
  });
};
```

and I want to unit test it (I think). I instrumented `mocha` to do the testing, but my test doesn't seem all that.. thorough:

```
describe('Finding the least used Passage', function() {
  it('should have a function called findLeastUsedPassage', function() {
    return expect(WorkbookLib.findLeastUsedPassage).to.exist;
  });
  return it('should return the least used passages for a student', function() {
    return WorkbookLib.findLeastUsedPassage(10).then(function(passageCounts) {
      var passageCountsLength;
      passageCountsLength = passageCounts.length;
      expect(passageCountsLength).to.equal(74);
      expect(passageCounts[0].count).to.be.at.most(passageCounts[1].count);
      expect(passageCounts[1].count).to.be.at.most(passageCounts[5].count);
      expect(passageCounts[56].count).to.be.at.most(passageCounts[70].count);
      return expect(passageCounts[70].count).to.be.at.most(passageCounts[73].count);
    });
  });
});
```

What's the right approach to unit testing something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://alistapart.com/article/writing-testable-javascript) is a great resource for understanding how to break up your code to able to test it.

Currently, you're code can't be tested well because the logic is all intermingled between multiple database calls, business logic, and glue code. What you need to do is break it all out into multiple named functions that each [do one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), like you do now. Expect that instead of creating the functions in the chain you should create them outside of the chain, then just call them in the promise chain.

```
var passageCounts = [];


function findAllActivePassages() {
  passageCounts = [];

  return db.Passage.findAll({
    where: {
      active: true
    }
  })
}

function countPassages(dbPassage) {
  var passage;
  passage = dbPassage.get();
  passage.count = 0;
  return passageCounts.push(passage);
}

function findAllSubjects(StudentId) {
  return db.Workbook.findAll({
    where: {
      SubjectId: 1,
      gradedAt: {
        $ne: null
      },
      StudentId: StudentId
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: db.WorkbookQuestion,
        include: [db.Question]
      }
    ],
    limit: 10,
    order: [['gradedAt', 'DESC']]
  });
}) 

// ...

findAllActivePassages()
  .each(countPassages)
  .then(function() {
    return findAllSubjects(studentId)
  })
  // ...
```

Now you can test each function individually and in isolation to ensure that they do what you expect

Comment: How would I then effectively test findAllActivePassages?

Comment: Since findAllActivePassages is just a database call, you probably don't need a unit test it so long as you trust that `db.Passage.findAll` will return correctly (3rd party code you don't need to unit test, only your only code)

Comment: So then, in my code, what would be something I'd want to test?

Comment: Whenever you do any data manipulation, business logic, or glue code. You could also test that any time you use any parameters in your database calls (like the studentId), that it uses it correctly. It really depends on how thorough you feel you want to be. At the very least you should test that the last two functions in your promise chain, where you look at the data returned from the database calls, do what you expect them to do.

Answer (score 1):

So for starters, you probably want to break up your promise chains to make the discrete units of your code more apparent. I did some quick psuedo javascript (most familliar w/ node so apologies if this doesn't fit vanilla javascript as cleanly).

```
var p1 = db.Passage.findAll({ where: { active: true }})
var p2 = db.Workbook.findAll({
      where: {
        SubjectId: 1,
        gradedAt: {
          $ne: null
        },
        StudentId: StudentId
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: db.WorkbookQuestion,
          include: [db.Question]
        }
      ],
      limit: 10,
      order: [['gradedAt', 'DESC']]
    });

Promise.all([p1, p2])
.then(function(results){
    var passages = results[0]
    var workbooks = results[1];

    var passageCounts = {};
    passages.foreach(function(passage){
        passagecounts[passage.get().id] = 0
    });

    workbooks.foreach(function(workbook){
        workbook.workBookQuestions.foreach(function(question){
            return passageCounts[dbWorkbookQuestion.Question.PassageId] += 1;
        })
    });

    return Promise.resolve(passageCounts)
}).then(function(passageCounts){
    passageCounts = _.sortBy(passageCounts, 'count'); //this has to change but don't know what underscore offers for sorting an object used as a hashmap
    return passageCounts;
});
```

Now as far as unit testing - you're looking to test discrete units of it so the following use cases seem reasonable:

- Do I get any result back when expected?
- If i give it specific values are they sorted in the way I expect?
- If I have no results for either query does it break? Should it?

It may behoove you to break out the DB calls from the logic and pass the results into a method, makes testing some of the scenarios a bit easier.